# Generating Dataset and Stacking Data

Tags: r

So I am supposed to generate a data set with `n=50` agents for the following:

```
Xi1,Xi2 ∼ N(1,1.5^2)
Ui1 ∼ N(0,Xi1^2)
εi ∼ N(0,2^2) 
Ui2 ∼ εi + 0.5Ui1
Yi1 = 1−0.5Xi1 +Ui1 
Yi2 = 1 − 0.5Xi2 + Ui2
```

where `i` subscript indicates the agent and the second subscript is treated as a time index.

Then I have to stack the data across individuals and time and end up with a matrix `[Y,X,U]` of the form `(nxT)x3` with `n=50` and `T=2`. I should end up with T rows in the data set corresponding to each `i` agent.

I have zero experience with `R`, with this being the first time using it and I am very confused about what I should be typing into the console to achieve this result. I've already read through the `R` help and googled different codes, but I'm still not sure how to work through this problem.

I would really appreciate some help in constructing this data set, because I really don't know where to even begin making this data.

Comment: You can start by looking at how to make `vectors`, then look at `rnorm` for generating vector of random normal values. Then look at vector addition and multiplication in R. Finally look at building `matrix` (and maybe even `array`) using `vectors`.

Comment: Hi @ElisiaHearts, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This may not be, but it feels like a homework assignment. While not forbidden here, that still leads many people to either avoid answering or to just give hints. Can you provide a little more context, and tell us what kind of help you're looking for? It may be that Stack Overflow is not a good fit for the kind of help you need; it's focused on specific questions rather than general help.